# AngularJS - Promise resolve and update view

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am trying to update an angular view from its controller using an ES6 Promise (fetch) resolved value. The thing is Angular does not update the view when my promise resolves, which is understandable tbh. This is a kind of radio app. Here's the code.

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', [
  'myPlayer', 'radio', function(player, radio) {

    // Some initilization

    this.next = function() {
      this.currentSong = this.upcomingSong;
      radio.nextSong().then(song => {
        this.upcoming = song;
      });
    };
```

and my view looks like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{player.upcomingSong.imgUrl}}" alt="{{player.upcomingSong.name}}">
<div>
    <p>{{player.upcoming.title}}</p>
    <p>{{player.upcoming.artist}}</p>
</div>
```

I've searched through the documentation and several questions and articles, but those seemed more complicated than they should be, cause I think I am missing something fundamental.

What is the proper way of implementing this?

Thanks.

Comment: what `nextSong` method has?

Answer (score -1):

By using the ES6 promise, you're leaving the angular scope. That means that angular doesn't know something has changed inside his component.

What you can do is

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', [
  'myPlayer', 'radio', '$timeout', function(player, radio, $timeout) {

    // Some initilization

    this.next = function() {
      this.currentSong = this.upcomingSong;
      radio.nextSong().then(song => {
        $timeout(() => {
          this.upcoming = song
        }, 0);
      });
    };
```

Using the `$timeout` service will make angular know about the change you made.

I'm not recommending this solution. I think you should rather use `$http` promises to avoid leaving angular scope.

Comment: Instead of using $timeout it is better to offer $applyAsync or use angular's $http service to stay with angular scope. In other case this $timeout will be all over's TS application.

Comment: @Vitalii That's what I said about `$http`. `$timeout()` is the most used solution, it will have the same result as `$applyAsync`.

Comment: No, it will not. The difference for them is pritty big. $timeout always splits code executing and $applyAsync will not.

Comment: No, it's not. It's a dirty hack. $scope.$apply() is a better solution, $http is a better solution, $q.when() is a better solution.

Comment: @Vitalii They are identical here, because the code surely isn't executed on digest. And $applyAsync is semantically correct.

Comment: @JBNizet So if instead of ES6 Promises, I used the $http service my code would work without any modifications?

Comment: @JBNizet @Vitalii we all agree `$http` is the best option. I sincerely think that injecting `$scope` inside a controller with "controller as" syntax is a very dirty thing to do.

Comment: Damn, I had the `radio` service written with `$http` at the beginning, but then I thought "Hey it's 2017, why not use `fetch`?! Probably that's why!

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Why would it be? It's still the only way to watch, emit, broadcast, and apply. The controller instance is still in the $scope.

Comment: @KostasDimakis yes. But you could also call $scope.$spply once you have set this.upcming. Or you could wrap the ES6 promise into a $q promise.

Comment: Guys, all of have contributed to solving my problem, you're welcome to write up an answer.

Comment: @JBNizet $watch is the reason angular had to be rewritten. $emit and $broadcast should never be used (services are always a better option). $applyAsync could be used, but only if you really know why.